# Install dotnet core version 1.1 runtime

Tags: linux, .net-core, fedora

I currently have dotnet core version 2 installed on my Fedora box, `dotnet --version` returns `2.0.0` as expected.

When I run an existing project targeting `netcoreapp1.1` with `dotnet run` I get:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.
```

(Note that `dotnet build` completes successfully on the project)

How do I install framework version runtime 1.1.2 with the current sdk (2.0.0), where `dotnet run` will work correctly with both new projects and projects targeting runtime 1.1.2?

In my neivity, I downloaded the 1.1.2 runtime and copied the 1.1.2 folder into my `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App` folder and have been rewarded with `Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500` when I run `dotnet run`... but I knew that wasn't how to do it before I even started.

As a side note, my Windows box has dotnet sdk 2, and runs the project fine... but that was all setup with Visual Studio black magic.

Comment: Use full path with 1.1.2 runtime, Ex: `/home/dotnet1.1.2/dotnet` because .net core sdk 2 yum installtion adds link to its `dotnet` in `/usr/bin`

Comment: That would break the 2.0.0 sdk though, then I wouldnt be able to build against 2.0.0... I want it like my windows box, the same sdk will build both runtimes.